# jquery input mask overwriting textbox value with asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins

I have an ASP.NET web form, and I'm using the masked input plugin from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin, which seems to be a pretty popular plugin. It works very well, but I'm having an issue when attempting to pre-populate a value in a textbox using the masking.

In my document.ready, Im performing:

```
$("#txtPrimaryPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999 ?x9999");
```

In my codebehind I set my text property like so:

```
txtPrimaryPhone.Text = "1234567890";
```

When my page loads, my textbox is empty.  Has anyone run into similar issues, or can anyone offer any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution :

Instead of

```
$("#txtPrimaryPhone").mask("(999) 999-9999 ?x9999");
```

Try this

```
 $.each($('#txtPrimaryPhone'), function (iEmt, emt) {
            $(emt).mask("(999) 999-9999 ?x9999").val($(emt).attr("value"));
        });
```

it works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

If I’m correct, the jQuery mask is applied once you load your page, then your txtPrimaryPhone.Text is set server side. I have two theories.

**One**: 1234567890 is not accepted by the mask because it is not in the right format. Right format should be something like txtPrimaryPhone.Text = “(999) 999-9999 x99999”;.

**Two**: The mask works as a filter for user input but does not accept the server side value for txtPrimaryPhone.
It’s a little hard to find out without a sample we can debug or edit.

Comment: Thanks Yushell, I tried pre-formatting the value before sending it to the screen, but it still didn't show.  Thanks for the insight though, appreciate it..